# read JSON Key 0 in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, http

I have a HTTP GET request that returns either:

```
{"events":"Event Goes Here"}
```

or

```
{"service":"Service goes here"}
```

At the moment I'm writing two HTTP Get functions so that when I get to:

```
 if let results: NSArray = jsonResult["services"] as? NSArray {
```

or

```
 if let results: NSArray = jsonResult["events"] as? NSArray {
```

I know that Im getting the services or the events Json data.

I want to be able to streamline the HTTP Get request so that I can call in a single function:

```
 func makeGETRequest(urlRequest: String) {
```

how do I read the string in json0 to be able to determine if its an event or a service?

Comment: Stupid question, is it just 'jsonResult[0]' ?

Comment: Can you add an example of urlRequest value?

Comment: http://status.example.com/services for the services one. and : http://status.example.com/service0/events for the events one.

Comment: how'bout `for (k, v) in d { /* do stuff with k and v */ break; }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to already know how to parse the data, but are asking how you might wrap it up to avoid redundancy.

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
func getStuff(urlRequest:String) -> Result
```

where Result is an enum with associated values for your payload.  Documentation [can be found here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID148)

You could then call the function something like this:

```
switch (getStuff("someUrl")) {
case let .Events(events):
    doStuffWith(events)
    break

case let .Service(serviceStuff):
    doStuffWith(serviceStuff)
    break
}
```

The baseline for the form you suggest though, is that if you want to use a common function, you have to return a multiplexed type.  Your other option, is for it to call type specific handler functions / closures for each of the possible types, so you are not relying on the return type, but are reacting to the results with further calls such that all processing is done by the time that your `getStuff()` function returns.

As far as actual parsing goes, you would just use a series of if-let unwrappings to check for which result you got.

Answer (score 0):

I don't do Swift, so translate the following ObjC to Swift and it may work, this is just a snippet, but this won't work because json[@"XXX"] requires an NSDitionary

```
- (id)initWithJson:(NSArray *)json
{
    NSArray* object = json[@"events"] ?: json[@"service"];

    self = [super initWithJson:object];
    if (self == nil)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    //do work

    return self;
}
```

so, you should try to reform your JSON packet that you get from the server, I can't image it being set up in a way that it doesn't send you a dictionary first that you must then parse to an array.

or something like this:

```
NSString * valueYouWant = json[@"events"] ?: json[@"service"];
```

using this:

```
-(NSString*)getValue:(NSDictionary*)json
{

    NSString * valueYouWant = json[@"events"] ?: json[@"service"];

    return valueYouWant;
}
```

you would call this by doing sending your "response object" from the server to the NSString method above